# Check constraint on biggest key of HSTORE in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I would like to create check constraint on the HSTORE field that contains data in a following format:

```
{ 
1 => 2020-03-01, 2 => 2020-03-07,  etc, etc, etc,
}
```

Where key is always a positive digit and value is a date.

Problem here that I want to extract keys ( by  `akeys`), and then somehow get the biggest key and compare it with  `number_of_episodes`(positive integer).
But it says that I can’t use arrays in check constraint.

Question is -is it possible to extract somehow biggest key from `HSTORE` as an integer and use it in check constraint afterwards?

Thank you.

```
alter table archives_seasonmodel
add constraint test
check (max((unnest(akeys(episodes))) <= number_of_episodes ))
```

This doesn’t work.

Comment: Please add actual error message.

Comment: With Postgres 12 something like that would be possible when using `jsonb` instead of `hstore`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me in PostgreSQL 10:

```
# create table tvseries 
  (number_of_episodes int, 
   episodes hstore, 
   check (number_of_episodes >= all (akeys(episodes)::int[]))
  );
CREATE TABLE

# insert into tvseries values (2, '1=>"a", 2=>"b"');
INSERT 0 1

# insert into tvseries values (1, '1=>"a", 2=>"b"');
ERROR:  new row for relation "tvseries" violates check constraint "tvseries_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, "1"=>"a", "2"=>"b").

# insert into tvseries values (2, '1=>"a"');
INSERT 0 1

# select * from tvseries;
 number_of_episodes |      episodes      
--------------------+--------------------
                  2 | "1"=>"a", "2"=>"b"
                  2 | "1"=>"a"
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28358529/16361) outlines a couple ways you can go about this. The first is to use the `intarray` extension and it's `sort_desc` function, but I think the better approach here is to use a custom function.

```
testdb=# create extension hstore;
CREATE EXTENSION
testdb=# create table tt0(h hstore, max_n bigint);
CREATE TABLE
testdb=# CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_greatest(anyarray)
RETURNS anyelement LANGUAGE SQL AS $$
SELECT max(x) FROM unnest($1) as x;
$$;
CREATE FUNCTION
testdb=# alter table tt0 add check((array_greatest(akeys(h)::integer[]))<=max_n);
ALTER TABLE
testdb=# insert into tt0 select hstore(ARRAY[['1','asdf'],['3','fdsa']]), 2;
ERROR:  new row for relation "tt0" violates check constraint "tt0_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains ("1"=>"asdf", "3"=>"fdsa", 2).
testdb=# insert into tt0 select hstore(ARRAY[['1','asdf'],['2','fdsa']]), 2;
INSERT 0 1
testdb=# select * from tt0
testdb-# ;
            h             | max_n 
--------------------------+-------
 "1"=>"asdf", "2"=>"fdsa" |     2
(1 row)

testdb=# \d tt0
                Table "public.tt0"
 Column |  Type  | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+--------+-----------+----------+---------
 h      | hstore |           |          | 
 max_n  | bigint |           |          | 
Check constraints:
    "tt0_check" CHECK (array_greatest(akeys(h)::integer[]) <= max_n)
```